# Min/Max of $f(x,y) = e^{xy}$ where $x^3+y^3=16$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of the function :$$f(x,y)=e^{xy}$$ 
constraint $$x^3+y^3=16$$

This is my problem in my workbook. When I solve, I'm just have one solution, so I cannot find other. Here is my solution:

$$f(x,y) = e^{xy}$$
$$g(x,y) = x^3+y^3-16$$
$t(x,y) = f(x,y) + \lambda*g(x,y)$
So we will have three equations by Lagrange Multiplier:

$$(1) y*e^{xy} + 3*\lambda*x^2 = 0$$
$$(2) x*e^{xy} + 3*\lambda*y^2 = 0$$
$$(3)x^3+y^3 = 16$$

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ $==>$ $y=0$ or $x=0$ --> false
if $t=0$ $==>$ $x=y=0$ ---> false

So, $x$,$y$ and $t$ cannot equal to 0.

So, we have from (1) (2) and (3):
$$\frac{e^{xy}}{-3*\lambda} = \frac{x^2}{y}$$
$$\frac{e^{xy}}{-3*\lambda} = \frac{y^2}{x}$$
$$==> x= y $$
==>$$ x = y = 2 $$

That is my solution. I just have one no, so I cannot find both min and max. Maybe something wrong with my solution. Please helps me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please avoid using multiline equations in the title in the future; it screws up the main page layout.

Comment: @N.I ah, I understand. Because I just view fomular from other post , I don't really know different $$ and $ :D

Comment: Basically \$ is for small, inline equations and \$\$ is for big, centered equations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not find more than one critical value when solving problems like this.  In your case, as seems to be confirmed when this question was asked on [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=544013/%22this%22) site, you only have one critical value.  To see if it's a min or max, you need to do some more work, though (see the last post in that thread).

I think you can convince yourself why this makes sense though (and why you've found a max and not a min).  For your constraint, we can take $x$ positive and as big as we like.  This puts a unique condition on $y$ and in particular forces it to be very close to $x$ in magnitude but $y < 0$.  Notice then that when you plug these numbers into $f(x,y)$, you get ("large" means large absolute magnitude) $$f(x,y) = e^{xy} = e^{(\text{large positive)} \cdot (\text{large negative})} = e^{\text{large negative}} \approx 0.$$

But notice we can't ever get to $0$, only arbitrarily close.  This is why there is no other critical point corresponding to a relative minimum: there is no relative minimum.

Answer (score 2):

As of maximum value of $f(x,y)$

$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{2} \geq {\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)}^3 \geq {\left(\frac{2\sqrt{xy}}{2} \right)}^3 \geq ({xy})^\frac{3}{2}$$

Using the identity :

$$\frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+a_3^m...a_n^m}{n} \geq {\left(\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3...+a_n}{n} \right)}^m$$

and $A.M \geq G.M$

we get,

$$ \:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ xy\;\;\;\;\leq\;\;\;\;\; 4$$

$$\longrightarrow \:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ e^{xy}\;\;\;\;\leq\;\;\;\;\; e^4$$

Comment: Oh. It likes x=y=2 case when I use Lagrange Multiplier. But at min case, I don't have any idea how to solve by Lagrange Multiplier

Comment: Yes I know that , I wrote this answer so that you know that x=y=2 by lagrange multiplier is correct for maximum case as you have cited in your question, as of the minimum case I am thinking on it. :)